# csv's writerow in python doesn't work most of the time

Tags: python, csv

I have some very simple piece of code:

```
import csv
out = csv.writer(open('test.csv', 'wb'), delimiter=",")
out.writerow([u"value1", u"value2", u"value3"])
```

It sometimes works, but most of the time it doesn't! I remember I used writerow previously and it was working just fine, what am I missing here?

To make the problem clearer: the csv file remains empty although the above code is executed without any errors

Comment: "doesn't work" is vague. Describe _how_ it doesn't work for you -- doesn't generate immediately visible output? Throws an exception? If the problem is that it isn't flushing to the file, well, that's a thing that can be easily solved, or will eventually fix itself when you close the output file.

Comment: In addition to the bufferring issue (to fix it; flush or close the file) look at [`UnicodeWriter` in the docs](http://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html) to see how to write Unicode to a file using arbitrary encoding (otherwise you might have issues if the encoding uses zero bytes e.g., utf-16).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I modified the code to look as follows:

```
import csv
f = open('test.csv', 'wb')
out = csv.writer(f, delimiter=",")
out.writerow([u"value1", u"value2", u"value3"])
f.close()
```

So all I've done is that I separated the `open('test.csv', 'wb')` and assigned it to `f`, so that I can use `f.close()` at the end. It works perfectly this way.

Comment: Nice one. By closing the stream you are forcing it to flush to disk.

Answer (score 2):

A slightly more Pythonic way of accomplishing what you're doing is to use a [context manager](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/compound_stmts.html#the-with-statement), which is designated by the `with` statement:

```
In [1]: import csv

In [2]: with open('test.csv', 'wb') as f:
   ...:     writer = csv.writer(f)
   ...:     writer.writerow([u"value1", u"value2", u"value3"])
```

When you use `with`, among other things, it ensures that the file is properly closed when the code exits the indented block. Also, when using the `csv` module, the default delimiter is `,`, so you can actually omit that from your `writer` (or `out`, in your case) declaration.

Answer (score 0):

I resolved the issue by focusing on how I was indenting the block which contained the csv.writer. I indented it in more, under some other iteration that I had done after reading it in.

```
with open('retrans.csv') as csvfile:
    file1 = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter = ',')
    print(file1)

    next(file1)

    count = 0
    for row in file1:
        while count < 1:
            print(row)  
            count +=1

            with open("newfile.csv", 'w', newline = '') as outfile:
                csv_writer = csv.writer(outfile, delimiter = ',')
                for lines in file1:
                    csv_writer.writerow(lines)
```